# Smart way to design long forms in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-resolution

I would like to create kind of an 'electronic questionnaire' with about 40 questions.
Designing the form (mainly consisting of Spinner elements), I found out that in QVGA resolution, I can place a maximum of 3 questions in a layout with a text size that is still readable for elder persons.

Now of course one solution would be to use a Scrollbox, but I imagine that to be quite inconvenient (and unclear: "did I miss a field somewhere above?") and maybe even "ugly".

On the other hand, just staying with 3 questions per layout, it must look ugly on larger displays.

I just wanted to ask how others solved this design challenge and if there are maybe smarter solutions than the ones that came to my own mind so far… 8-/

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I do have a link that might help for this type of topic: http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, that looks indeed very interesting. For now, I took the tip to add a ProgressBar to at least give users an indication on how far they made it already... A very useful site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different layouts for different screen sizes and resolutions would probably be the best way to handle this. Please see [this article on the Android Developers Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources) for more information. Also, long forms (from a design and usability standpoint) can be kind of daunting, so from a human perspective I would recommend doing a few questions per page to prevent users from getting frustrated.

Comment: That's what I almost thought already … that there might be a way to create different layouts for different resolutions .. and thanks for the link. 
However, how to solve that programmatically? Let's say, Android decides it is dealing with a large layout - how would *I* know that and code accordingly? That even goes as far as that I would maybe have up to 10 screens on a small display, but only need 1 on a large one -- almost completely different code in terms of checking input, saving status data and results, opening the next layout/page/activity etc. ?!